# React-native Horizontal scroll View animate to end

Tags: android, ios, animation, react-native, scrollview

I have images in scrollview horizontal, I just want that on First swipe all images scroll to end with smooth animation so that user can see all of them with one swipe.

By using prop scrollToEnd is not helping me as it scrolls way too fast.

Here is my current code .

```
   <ScrollView 
    contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
    horizontal={true}
    ref="scrollview"
    onScrollEndDrag={()=> this.refs.scrollview.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}
    >
    <Image width={1800}  source={require('./assets/1.png')} />
    <Image width={1800}  source={require('./assets/2.png')} />
    <Image width={1800}  source={require('./assets/3.png')} />
    <Image width={1800}  source={require('./assets/4.png')} />
    <Image width={1800}  source={require('./assets/5.png')} />
    <Image width={1800}  source={require('./assets/7.png')} />
    <Image width={1800}  source={require('./assets/8.png')} />
    <Image width={1800}  source={require('./assets/9.png')} />
    <Image width={1800}  source={require('./assets/10.png')} />
  </ScrollView>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
cover: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: "90%"
}
```

});

Comment: plus refs is defined just missed here.
   <ScrollView 
        contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
        horizontal={true}
        ref="scrollview"
        onScrollEndDrag={()=> this.refs.scrollview.scrollToEnd({animated: false})}
        >

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `FlatList` instead of ScrollView you can use it as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList, Text} from "react-native";

const data = [
  {
    imageUrl: require('./assets/1.png'),
    title: "something"
  },
  {
    imageUrl: require('./assets/2.png'),
    title: "something two"
  }

];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: data
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item: rowData }) => {
          return (
         <Image width={1800}  source={rowData.imageUrl} />
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I didn’t test the code, but i think this should work, it my require some slight modifications

Hope it will helps

Comment: This was not my problem was. I already have a horizontal scrolling view. Want to animate slowly to end.